# What should be the image size for android splash screen?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to create a splash screen with the [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package. I'm using the same image as my logo but the splash image seems to be small. So what should be the ideal size for the splash image? I've already handled the Android 12 splash image as the dimensions are given on the package page but no dimensions are given for the lower versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on your design, but usually splash screen should be full screen regardless of screen size. Here, I have put some codes for example:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(48.0),
    child: body: new Image.network(
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/21/21/13/unicorn-2087450_1280.png",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    ),
  );
}
```